# How to fix dependabot security alert wasmtime vulnerable to guest-controlled out-of-bounds read/write on x86_64

Tags: security

I forked my parachain from substrate-node-template (polkadot-v0.9.29).

Dependabot has generated following security alert:

**wasmtime vulnerable to guest-controlled out-of-bounds read/write on x86_64**

Dependabot can not patch the security issue automatically with the following error from dependabot:

"Dependabot cannot update cranelift-codegen to a non-vulnerable version

The latest possible version of cranelift-codegen that can be installed is 0.85.3.

The earliest fixed version is 0.91.1."

I tried to do it  manually by executing the following command:

cargo update -p cranelift-codegen

but the said package is not updated and no error message is generated.

Can some one guide me, how to fix this error?[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not really a support question. 

`0.9.29` is quite old, please upgrade and then the wasmtime version will also be upgraded.

Comment: Thank you for your response @bkchr.

Comment: So we decided to upgrde to v0.9.38. Will this security alert will vanish once we upggrade to that specific version?

Comment: Yeah should probably be enough.